# Should I use django-activity-stream combined with django-notifications?

Tags: django, django-notification, django-activity-stream

I'm discovering `django-activity-stream`, I would like to use it on our website for showing a news feed based on follow relationships (like Twitter) and a profile feed. It seems perfect for doing this.

However, it doesn't seem really great for notifications feed. So :

- Should I use `django-notifications` which is dedicated for this use case ? (Maybe both framework are meant to work as a pair, is there specific configuration for that ?)
- Or should I just tweak `django-activity-stream`(considering that both framework are based on the same structure) and how ?

FYI : I don't need template features as I'm building a REST API (with `django-rest-framework`).

Comment: Which setup did you go with?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use both packages for their own purpose. Just follow their docs and you will get many thing answered.

`django-notification` is based on `django-activity-stream` and can be used for github-like notifications. you can serialize the django motifications models with django rest framework.

Comment: bad idea. if one is building a scalable performant app. using two 3rd party packages that rely on generic foreign keys, will have a heavy toll on queries.